# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script...Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, tensorflow

I am currently following a js tutorial that uses TensorFlow for handwritten character detection, but I am getting errors despite having the same code & file layout as the person I am following. Here is my error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

localhost/:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I believe this is happening because of the following lines:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import * as tf from '../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { MNIST_DATA } from './data.js';
```

My file directory is as follows:
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJWkr.png)

Here is a basic reproduction of what I have so far:

```js
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import * as tf from '../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { MNIST_DATA } from './data.js';

console.log("main script loaded...");

var model;

function create () {

    model = tf.sequential();

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({

        inputShape: [28, 28, 1],
        kernelSize: 5,
        filter: 8,
        strides: 1,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({

        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2, 2],

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({

        kernelSize: 5,
        filter: 16,
        strides: 1,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({

        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2, 2],

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.flatten());

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({

        units: 10,
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
        activation: 'softmax',

    }));


    model.compile({

        optimizer: tf.train.sgd(.15),
        loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',

    });


}

create();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html leng = "en">

    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" 
                type = "text/css" 
                href = "style.css" 
                media = "screen"/>
    
        <script type = "module"
                src = "main.js"
                defer> </script>
    
        <meta charset  = "utf-8">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <style>
    
            .prediction-canvas {
    
                width: 100px;
                margin: 20px;
    
            }
    
            .prediction-div {
    
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 10px;
    
            }
    
        </style>

        <div class = "container" style = "padding-top: 20px;">

            <div class = "card">

                <div class = "card-header">

                    <strong> Alpha Vision </strong>

                </div>

                <div class = "card-body">

                    <div class = "card">

                        <div class = "card-body">

                            <h5 class = "card-title">

                                <strong> log </strong>
                                <div id = "log"> </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class = "card">

                        <div class = "card-body">

                            <h5 class = "card-title"> predict </h5>

                            <button type= "button" 
                                    class = "btn btn-primary" 
                                    id = "selectTestDataButton"
                                    disabled> waiting for model... </button>

                            <div id = "predictionResult"> </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

How can I fix this error? Without TensorFlow, I cannot create a model. I tried viewing posts on SO with similar errors, but they all had to do with server-side code & angular, rather than node.js and tfjs.

Please let me know if my post is lacking any details!